# What is on the table vs. What are on the table

Tags: wh-questions

I am a native speaker teaching English. I ran into a sentence that sounded odd to me.

- What are on the table?

Grammarly says it should change to **is** however, if I modify the sentence slightly by adding **these** or **those** then it will be correct.

- What are these on the table?
- What are those on the table?

My question is, if I am talking about plural nouns on a table why do I not use **are** unless the Demonstrative Adjectives are used.

Comment: I am not going to give a formal answer because I am not sure of my response and cannot cite an authority that I trust. (Grammarly is not a site I trust). But my feeling is that when there is neither context nor words indicating a plural, the default in English is singular.

Comment: *these* and *those* are the plural forms of *this* and *that*. It's a different issue since it's clearly plural in those sentences.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Since the sentence is clearly used in 3rd person can't we assume that the use of **are** alone makes the sentence plural?

Comment: @StamatiosStamoulas Like you, I found the original sentence odd. We are both native speakers. Thus I think we can trust our mutual agreement on what is idiomatic. Going to your question in the previous comment, the number of the subject determines the number of the verb, not vice versa. “I are happy” is ungrammatical. The use of “are” does not change the meaning of “I” to “we.”